# Does Xcode strip debug symbols for dependencies (OSX) and places them into .dSYM?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, libraries, dsym

My OSX app has several dependency libraries which were compiled with `-g` clang flag to preserve source-level debug symbols. 
Xcode project settings have `Strip Debug Symbols During Copy` set to `YES` and `Debug Information Format` set to `DWARF with dSYM`.

However, whenever I read a symbolicated crash report, the backtrace frames on the app-level are correctly symbolicated but library-level frames are just memory addresses. This makes me think that Xcode did not put dependencies' symbols data into dSYM package. How one could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem.
One should use `dsymutil` to extract dSYM package from an arbitrary binary compiled with source-level symbols (`-g` flag for `clang` on OSX).

I wrote this script to automatically extract dSYMs from my dependencies and place them into the Archive and added it to the `Post-build action` of the `Archive` stage in project configuration:

```
log="/tmp/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}-release.log"
echo "********* Adding dependencies dSYMs into the archive..." > $log
function copyLibDsym()
{
    local lib=$1
    local libfile=$(basename $lib)
    local libname="${libfile%.*}"
    echo "extracting dSYMs from ${libname} to ${ARCHIVE_DSYMS_PATH}/${libname}.dSYM" >> $log
    dsymutil "$lib" -o "${ARCHIVE_DSYMS_PATH}/${libname}.dSYM"
}

ndnrtclib="${NDNRTC_LIB_PATH}/libndnrtc.dylib"
ndncpplib="${NDNCPP_LIB_PATH}/libndn-cpp.dylib"
discoverylib="${NDNCHAT_LIB_PATH}/libentity-discovery.dylib"
chatlib="${NDNCHAT_LIB_PATH}/libchrono-chat2013.dylib"

copyLibDsym $ndnrtclib
copyLibDsym $ndncpplib
copyLibDsym $discoverylib
copyLibDsym $chatlib
```

Archive's dSYMs folder now have several .dSYM packages which can be used for proper crash reports symbolication.